# Forcing a client class to implement a child class' interface?

Tags: java, interface, javafx

I have a custom "widget" (custom control) that any class may use in their layout. If they are going to be using this widget, however, they must implement its interface. This widget has an interface called WidgetInterface, with only one method called handleAction().

If the Parent class wants to use this widget, how should it do so?

Construct the Widget and pass a reference of itself to its constructor?

```
Widget newWidget = new Widget(this);
```

Construct the Widget with a type parameter as itself?

```
Widget<Parent> newWidget = new Widget<Parent>(this);
```

The widget class will have to check to make sure that parent class is implementing its interface using either instanceof, or generics. .

The parent class gets to choose what to do with handleAction(), of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first constructor is right.

This is an example of "polymorphism" in action, which has to do with an object being referenced as though it's an object of a class that it extends or an interface that it implements. In your example the class using the Widget implements the interface WidgetInterface which means instances of it are also instances of WidgetInterface. There's a lot of info on the net and here on StackExchange explaining this in detail so I won't go into it anymore here. As a start check out [the java tutorial on inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html) particularly the section on polymorphism.

In Widget define the constructor as

```
public Widget(WidgetInterface actionhandler)
```

Then you can pass in an object of any type as long as it implements WidgetInterface.